# E470 TrackPoint not working on CentOS 7

Tags: linux, centos, thinkpad

I have recently purchased a thinkpad e470 and installed CentOS 7 on it but found that the trackpoint as well as the trackbuttons (above touchpad) aren't working but when I was installing using centos liveusb they worked properly..and I thought the same for post-installation. BUT this isn't the case. Even more the xinput is not listing the trackpoint even, it outputs only the touchpad and virtual core pointer.

Comment: You could try follow [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/TrackPoint) wiki.